# Mysql calling procedure failed when dynamically alter table in it

Tags: mysql, procedure

I want to alter my tables dynamically based on whether the table has specific column.

My database name is `summer_cms`, and there are over 50 tables in it.

What I want are below:

1. If a table has a column named `add_time`, then I would like to add a column `add_user_id` in it.
2. Similarly, I would like to add `update_user_id` in the table if `update_time` is found.

I know I should get it down in the process of creating the database schemas, but my database has been built and I have to alter it by need.

So I create a procedure to do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ALTER_SUMMER_TABLE()
BEGIN
    DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE exitence VARCHAR(64);

    DECLARE ntable INT;    # number of tables
    DECLARE i INT;         # index
    SET i = 0;

    # get the count of table
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(TABLE_NAME)) INTO ntable FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'summer_cms';

    WHILE i < ntable DO
        # select the specific table name into the variable of `tableName`.
        SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO tableName
        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'summer_cms'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'add_time'
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET i;

        # alter table, but I get error in this clause.
        ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN `add_user_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'add user id';

        # check if the table has `update_time`
        SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO exitence
        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'summer_cms'
        AND TABLE_NAME = tableName
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'update_time';

        # add `update_user_id` if `update_time` be found.
        IF exitence THEN
            ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN `update_user_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'update user id';
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

But I got an error when I call this procedure.

```
Procedure execution failed
1146 - Table 'summer_cms.tableName' doesn't exist
```

Dose anyone could tell me what I was missing or wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Means what it says -try using dynamic sql.

Comment: @P.Salmon Through other way, I could confirm that the variable `tableName` has been assigned a value. I just don't know why this was happened.

Comment: True but there is no variable substitution in the alter statement - it thinks it's altering a table called tablename.

Comment: @P.Salmon Could you please tell me how to fix the `procedure` to solve my question? Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a a few alterations you can make to your procedure to make it more streamlined as well as getting round a few problems.

First using a cursor to select the table names rather than using the two selects your using.  Secondly to use a prepared statement to allow you to dynamically set the table name...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ALTER_SUMMER_TABLE`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(64);
    declare cur cursor for SELECT TABLE_NAME
                             FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'summer_cms'
                            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'add_time';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    open cur;

    start_loop: loop
        fetch cur into tableName;
        if (done = 1 )THEN
             LEAVE start_loop;
        END IF;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', tableName,' ADD COLUMN `add_user_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;

    end loop;

    close cur;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You could do a few tweaks - only fetch table names where the column doesn't already exist for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It would be very helpful if you could tell me what I was wrong in my procedure.

Comment: @paul the one point I made, which is in the comments as well is about the alter table statement, you have to build statements as strings if you want to do substitutions for things like table names or column names.  Binding only works with values in SQL (so for example the `'add_time'` bit in the first SQL could be bound but not the `COLUMN_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of dynamic sql

```
drop procedure if exists alter_table;
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  procedure alter_table()

begin
declare tablename varchar(20);
set tablename = 'u';

set @sqlstmt =  concat('ALTER TABLE ', tableName, ' ADD COLUMN ', char(96), 'add_user_id', char(96), ' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT', char(39), 'add user id', char(39),';');
prepare stmt from @sqlstmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end //

delimiter ;
```

Note I have used ascii backticks and single quotes.